# Google Dataflow late data

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have been reading the Dataflow SDK documentation, trying to find out what happens when data arrives past the watermark in a streaming job.

This page:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing

indicates that if you use the default window/trigger strategies, then late data will be discarded:

> Note: Dataflow's default windowing and trigger strategies discard late data. If you want to ensure that your pipeline handles instances of late data, you'll need to explicitly set .withAllowedLateness when you set your PCollection's windowing strategy and set triggers for your PCollections accordingly.

Yet this page:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/triggers

indicates that late data will be emitted as a single element PCollection when it arrives late:

> The default trigger for a PCollection is event time-based, and emits the results of the window when the system's watermark (Dataflow's notion of when it "should" have all the data) passes the end of the window. The default trigger emits on a repeating basis, meaning that any late data will by definition arrive after the watermark and trip the trigger, causing the late elements to be emitted as they arrive.

So, will late data past the watermark be discarded completely? Or, will it only not be emitted with the other data it would have been windowed with had it arrived in time, and be emitted on its own instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default "windowing and trigger strategies" discard late data. The `WindowingStrategy` is an object which consists of windowing, triggering, and a few other parameters such as allowed lateness. The default allowed lateness is 0, so any late data elements are discarded.

The default trigger handles late data. If you take the default `WindowingStrategy` and change only the allowed lateness, then you will receive a `PCollection` which contains one output pane for all of the on time data, and then a new output pane for approximately every late element.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer @ben. So if I am understanding this correctly with the default windowing strategy:  
* Data arriving on time will be emitted in one output pane.
* Data points arriving late but within the allowedLateness will be emitted in its own output pane (approximately).
* Data points arriving later than the allowedLateness will be discarded.
What approaches are there to capture the data that comes in later than the allowedLateness? One of our use cases for dataflow is a billing system where every query needs to be counted eventually, regardless of how late it arrives

Comment: All data that arrives after the allowedLateness is discarded. If you want to respond to all late data, you should set the allowedLateness accordingly. In typical use cases there is a point (day/week/month) after which late data will no longer be accepted. The system needs to retain data for every window until it the allowedLateness is so far past that no more data will be considered for that window. There are typically values of allowed lateness after which the late data is so unlikely as to never happen, or if it does the data is so late it is not actionable.